# Elasticsearch on nested hash

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I have a nested hash of users and profiles(i.e: one user embeds one profile). How will the elasticsearch uri be if i want to query based on usernames(which are present in profile)?

Comment: Earlier I was logging each field of the profile object and I was able to query like http://localhost:9292/v1/search/users?q=username:robocat.But now I am logging the entire user object

Comment: Don't you want to query using [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html)?

Comment: I want to use the uri query for my http endpoint